# Good example needed: when would templateShareable=true be useful?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, web-applications, sapui5

In the [UI5 documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.74.0/#/topic/3a4a9e562988456c9be0ef883ae7da50) there is a thorough explanation how the property `templateShareable` in an Aggregation Binding works and what it does. There are even rules when to use which value. The rule for `templateSharable=true` says:

> Use this option in the following cases only:
>
> - The template is reused in your app to define an additional list binding. [...]
> - The parent control that contains the list binding with the template is cloned. The binding info is used in the clone as well. [...]

I understand these statements, but I have a hard time imagining what this would look like. Can anyone point me to a good *example* where one of these conditions are fulfilled?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit what a _good example_ may look like compared to the existing one given by the doc? Are you looking for real world use cases?

Answer (score 2):

There's a useful example right there in the documentation though.

```
<Table id="EmployeeEquipments" headerText="Employee Equipments" items="{
    path: 'EMPLOYEE_2_EQUIPMENTS',
    templateShareable: false
}">
    <columns>
        <!-- ... -->
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{ID}"/>
            </cells>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{EQUIPMENT_2_PRODUCT/Name}"/>
            </cells>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{Category}"/>
            </cells>
            <cells>
                <!-- Name="PRODUCT_2_CATEGORY" Type="Collection(...)" -->
                <List items="{
                    path: 'EQUIPMENT_2_PRODUCT/PRODUCT_2_CATEGORY',
                    templateShareable: true
                }">
                    <StandardListItem title="{CategoryName}"/>
                </List>
            </cells>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{EQUIPMENT_2_PRODUCT/PRODUCT_2_SUPPLIER/Supplier_Name}"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

I see a list inside of a table. The table is used once, since it defines a single table (`templateShareable: false`). Inside each table line is a cell that contains a list, so the list is created many times - once per table line - so the definition of the list is *cloned* for every row, or whenever a row is added to the table and therefore needs: `templateShareable: true`.